# Comment_total is displaying total number of ALL comments, not just open status

Tags: channel-entries, comments, status

I've been testing the default comments module, and noticed that when I use {comment_total} in the channel entries tag above my comments block, it displays the total amount of any comments for that blog post, so even if I have 5 open status, 5 closed, it shows 10 total comments. How can I filter it to only display open comment totals? I have included some of the code below. I can't just go in and recount statistics on channel entries every week, I need it to start out -only- displaying {comment_total} with a status of Open.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" status="Open"}
{head}
    <h6>There are {comment_total} comments on this post. <a href="#comments">Skip to comments &raquo</a></h6>
        <h3>Submit a comment:</h3>
        {!-- comment form tag is here --}
        {embed="view/.commentview"}
        {!-- .commentview embed contains the display of all comments associated with this post --}
</body>
</html>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```